# Android Studio causing issue after SDK update installation failed

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, build.gradle, build-tools

I have tried to updating my SDK and after downloading some how installation failed.

I have also tried to re-install Android Studio.

[image]

I have already installed all build-tool versions.

[image]

Now I am not able to run any project as my studio not detecting any build-tools. As previously it was working with same SDK and android studio.

Comment: You have to update the support libraries repository in SDK Manager.

Comment: I have updated that still problem was occur , but fortunately able to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Fount solution that as my SDK installation failed , it affect my path to support library

> extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support`

I have my SDK backup  so from that have have replaced

```
m2repository
```

it solve my problem.